# Looking for audio record to google drive on OS X

Tags: osx, audio-recording, google-drive

I would like to record audio from my iMac default microphone to google drive automatically.

I took a look at a couple of Google Chrome apps, however, neither of them auto-sync / auto-record to Google Drive...

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-audio-recorder/coiefjfjbldcapekmclpdfemapaifbmh

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mic-note-voice-recorder-n/nhkoenoennbjnibepkjdheodiaojdgpk?hl=en
```

I looked in the iTunes Store, and found one very similar to the above two, but still no auto-sync

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/recorderhq-audio-recorder/id592288593?mt=8
```

If anyone knows about a audio recorder for OS X that will record audio, and then auto upload those recordings to google drive, even if it splits the recordings up into chunks, would be greatly appreciated...